# Is there a way to create an instance of a 'rallycard' outside of a cardboard?

Tags: rally

In the documentation, regarding the 'rallycard' object, it states: "In general, this class will not be created directly but instead will be instantiated by Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard as specified by its cardConfig". I have a model of a feature and I want to show it as a card like this (below) but it is not shown in the rendered page.

```
var card = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
        style: {
            position: 'absolute',
            left: '100px', //left + 'px',
            top: '100px'//top + 'px'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'rallycard',
            record: feature
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
     });

     this.down('#main').add(card);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a way to do this. Since I didn't see an example anywhere I'll answer my own question (code below). You'll have to find a meaningful value for objectId.

```
    Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
        type: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
        success: function(model) {
            var objectId = 1234; // <-- your objectId here
            model.load(objectId, {
                fetch: ['Name', 'State', 'Owner'],
                callback: function(result, operation) {
                    if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                        var owner = result.get('Owner');
                        console.log('owner', owner._refObjectName);

                        var card = Ext.create('Rally.ui.cardboard.Card', {
                            style: {
                                position: 'absolute',
                                left: '100px',
                                top: '200px',
                                width: '200px'
                            },
                            record: result
                        });
                        this.down('#main').add(card);
                    }
                },
                scope: this
            });
        },
        scope: this
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a console error?  I would guess there are probably a few other required config options in addition to card that are tripping you up.

One other small note, you don't need both a renderTo and a call to add.  In this case I'd probably drop the renderTo.

Comment: i appreciate your time Kyle. After walking away and starting a simple example I figured it out.

Comment: great!  glad you got it!